# jQuery Multiple .ajaxSuccess, load different functions specifically for each ajaxSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to load different functions specifically for different ajaxSuccess in one page.

I have multiple ajax in one page and I cannot figure a away to be more specific on which ajaxSuccess happen.

at the moment I am using:

```
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
        func1();
    });

// Ajax1 success => load func1()

// Ajax 2 success => load func2()

// Ajax 3 success => load func3()
```

Comment: how did you handled the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach separate successs methods to each call using

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "url",
    data:"{}",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(response){},
    error :  function(response){}
});

using this approach you can call specific success method attached to each ajax call. you don't need to bind every call to one common AjaxSuccess. and if you want to do so, then you need to send some kind of ID in response to call specific function.

e.g

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(response){
if (response.ID==1)
    func1();
else if (response.ID==2)
    func2();
```

});

Hope that helps.

Comment: can u please explain the solution a little bit? the code you wrote. @Muhammad

Answer (score 0):

I think it's connected to the fact that you it's working async so they don't really have to and shouldn't finish at the exactly queue they are being called. You can attach something like functionId to the json response to handle it properly.

Comment: is here a way to name the ajax, so it can be called back $(ajaxName).ajaxSuccess(function(){
        func1();
    });